# Padding left is not working as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to give a padding left to an element and that does seem to work in ie but when i am copying the same code from my laptop to development server it is not working .any reasons as to why?

Here's the code:

```
level1 td:first-child {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 100px;

}
```

Any alternative to padding that i can apply.

Comment: The HTML is the same?

Comment: You have a <level1> element in your markup? Maybe it's a class or an ID?

Comment: provide html code. and explain more exactly what you would like to have and what you really have.... with those information we can only guess in the dark

Comment: I am creating a table which has 5 columns and multiple rows(depending on the data) at runtime which has level1 as one of the class of a row something like <tr data-depth=\"1\" class=\"level1\">.So that is what a level 1 is....Next by td:first-child i want only the first column to have some padding from left.
All of this is working from my laptop's code but not from development server's code even though i have verified thoroughly that at both the places the code is same.
Any other info needed?

Comment: so you're missing a dot in front of your selector

Comment: Are you sure the stylesheet is even loading on the server.

Comment: Define "It's not working". Saying "My car isn't working" to a mechanic doesn't help much.

Comment: Finally i got the answer,it was when i changed the level1 to someothername and also removed--- td:first-child---....so it was like ....
----.mob{
    padding-left: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
}------
because i think somewhere in my stylesheet i had used level1 and it was overriding everything else.
And no it was not because of the dot ,i just missed to paste here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the time and effort spent.